# A tricky derivation accompanied by delta function

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, fourier-transform, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions, thermal-field-theory

I have been reading a book on Thermal Field theory by Michel Le Bellac During the reading I have come into a seemingly trivial but indeed tricky derivation. On page 26(2.47), we are supposed too prove
$$
(1-exp[-\beta k_0])\delta (k_0+E_n-E_m)=\delta (k_0+E_n-E_m)-\delta (k_0+E_m-E_n)
$$
Does anyone know which property of delta function can yield this result? Thx for generous help

Answer (score 2):

He is showing the symmetry properties. You need to look at the full
equation; it is not a property of the delta function. The relevant
part is the sum
\begin{eqnarray}
S &=&
\sum_{n,m} e^{-\beta E_n}(1-e^{-\beta k_0})
\delta(k_0+E_n-E_m)
\langle n|\hat q(0)|m\rangle|^2
\nonumber\\
&=&
\sum_{n,m} e^{-\beta E_n}
\delta(k_0+E_n-E_m)
\langle n|\hat q(0)|m\rangle|^2
\nonumber\\
&&-\sum_{n,m} e^{-\beta E_n} e^{-\beta k_0}
\delta(k_0+E_n-E_m)
|\langle n|\hat q(0)|m\rangle|^2
\end{eqnarray}
The delta function requires $k_0 = E_m-E_n$ so that
\begin{equation}
e^{-\beta E_n} e^{-\beta k_0} \delta(k_0+E_n-E_m)
= e^{-\beta E_m}\delta(k_0+E_n-E_m)
\end{equation}
The second term is then
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n,m}
e^{-\beta E_m}\delta(k_0+E_n-E_m)
|\langle n|\hat q(0)|m\rangle|^2 = 
\sum_{n,m}
e^{-\beta E_n}\delta(k_0+E_m-E_n)
|\langle n|\hat q(0)|m\rangle|^2
\end{equation}
where
since $m$ and $n$ are dummy variables, we can interchange their names.
(Alternatively, substitute $n'=m$, $m'=n$, and then since the primes
are redundant, drop them), and
$|\langle n|\hat q(0)|m\rangle|^2 = |\langle m|\hat q(0)|n\rangle|^2$.
The result is
\begin{equation}
S=\sum_{n,m} e^{-\beta E_n} \left [
\delta(k_0+E_n-E_m)
-\delta(k_0-E_m+E_n)\right ]
\langle n|\hat q(0)|m\rangle|^2 \,,
\end{equation}
which is his result.